# IntelliJ IDEA "Cannot find 'require'"

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rspec

When using the Ruby plug-in with IntelliJ, what "undefined reference" warnings should I expect/tolerate, and which indicate that I don't have something configured correctly?

For example, I am getting "Cannot find" warnings for 'require', 'File', and  'FileUtils'.  I suspect that this indicates a configuration problem.

I am also getting warnings for RSpec methods like 'describe', 'before', 'after, and 'it'.  Should I also be able to configure IntelliJ to "find" these?

Comment: Would it be possible to use RubyMine instead? It is a JetBrains product specific to Ruby Development and works very well with code completion as well as testing frameworks.

Comment: Seconding the recommendation for RubyMine over IntelliJ + Ruby plug in.  RubyMine is a solid piece of kit.

Comment: This project is a Java project using Ruby/RSpec to drive system tests.  I'm not sure how convenient it would be to move just the system tests to a different IDE.  Besides, doesn't IntelliJ's Ruby plug-in just use RubyMine code?

Comment: Considering the cost of each IDE, suggesting we use a separate (also paid) IDE instead of the (alleged) all-in-one IntelliJ doesn't really help ...

Answer (score 4):

You need to select the Ruby SDK in the Project Strucure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> by default).

Unfortunately it does not solve the warnings for rspec related words.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I do have the Ruby STK set, and I'm still getting the lines under both "require" and 'open3' in the very first line of my code.

Answer (score 0):

File > Project Structure > Project > Select Ruby SDK